# Weird Visual Studio 2008 behaviour: build failed, no error message?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

**EDIT: It's VS 2008 NOT VS 2005. Sorry for the typo**.
 
While trying to build two fairly big projects solution on Visual Studio 2008 (2 projects: 6686 files), and after making sure that everything is OK, my projects wouldn't build. VS informs me that the build failed but it doesn't tell me what I'm erring!? I tried cleaning, rebuilding, rebooting, almost everything. Ideas? 
 
**EDIT2: Problem solved, but ...** 
I moved the project over to another directory, then moved it back again to the same old directory, and magically it worked! :S No idea what was wrong though :S

Comment: Does it fail immediately or do you get some output in the build output window?

Comment: No it goes some short, then breaks. The last item to be built is an aspx page, checked, and nothing wrong with it. The version on my machine is identical to the version on the source control [Which builds perfectly smooth].

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: Anything special about that file that is fails after? First/last file in the directory? Can you omit that file?

Comment: 6686 files in 2 projects, that is huge! I would clean delete the solution from disk, re get from source control and try again. Youll prob find one of the files is locked. Unlocker tool can help you with this.

Comment: I still have the same issue. However, it still does create an install and the application installs correctly

Comment: @Galilyou How did you move it. Explorer using Cut and Paste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, obviously there's no logic that I know in the following answer, but it worked after I moved the project to another directory and then moved it back to its original directory again. 
 
**Thanks anyway guys**

Comment: I had the same issue. Copied all the source files out of the original directory into another temporary directory. Made a new folder. Copied the source files from the temporary directory to the new folder. Loaded the solution up and now it works! I did notice visual studio doing some extra things when it reloaded the project. Maybe there was a configuration file stuffed up or something. Bizarre! Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you get better error messages if you track down the build command (its in the output windows) and looks like

```
E:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorrep...blah..blah
```

Then run that manually at the command line.

Also, the output window tends to have better information, even though Visual Studios default behavior is to show the "Errors List" window after a failed build.

Comment: Couldn't do it. The build command is too long, cmd wouldn't let me paste in that much of a comment.

Comment: Had similar "Build Failed" problem in Visual C# 2010 Express... the solution was also the Output Window.

In the menus, select "Debug" => "Windows" => "Output", then select "Build" from the dropdown and you can see build errors that (for whatever reason) sometimes don't show up in the Error List.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Javascript codes or files + there are errors in these codes;

Visual Studio 2005 doesnt have the ability to debug them.but they added Javascript Debugging Feature in Visual STudio 2008.Maybe you should re-debug it in VS2008

If you are sure there are no Javascript errors or you didnt use Javascript codes & files,Visual Studio Team Edition has some nice *new project types.

If you create a new Test Project on your current project & then add an Unit Test,theres a high oppurtunity that you can see the errors.

If there are other details about your project situation,let us know

Cheers

Ibrahim Ersoy

Comment: Thanks for the response Ibrahim, but I really don't understand what Javascript errors have to do with Build errors!

Comment: as i thought so,but you have to consider all things when it comes to VS Debugger

Answer (score 0):

When you say cleaning, you mean Right Clicking on the Solutions and clicking Clean Solutions?

Have you tried removing all the built dlls from the Bin folder manually and making sure no other running applications have files open.

Not sure if its sill an issue with VS, but files or folders starting with a "." can cause problems. eg if SubVersion is not set to use "_svn" instead of ".svn"

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the project root the root of the drive. I had run into an issue with a very large project where the path length was so long it had started to cause issues.

So rather than:

```
c:\My Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Projects\MyProject
```

do this:

```
c:\MyProject
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a missing reference or potentially you are referencing something from the GAC that is not installed on your build server.

I would start by deleting the project completely from my local file system then do a force get-latest from TFS to rebuild the project directory.

Once done, I would try to build the project.  If there is a failure, go fix it.

If there isn't a failure, I would look through ALL of the referenced assemblies to ensure that any third party items are not pointing to the GAC.  MS ones are okay.. Provided you have the same service pack level between your machine and the build server.

If you still haven't found it, I would then move to remoting into the build server and trying to compile it from the Visual Studio that's installed on it.

As a potential other issue, if this is a web application (not a web site), then I would delete the designer file associated with that page it breaks on, right click on the .aspx file and select "convert to web application"  This will recreate the designer file.. and give you any error messages associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the output window and search for the keyword "unable". When you find what it was unable to do, you'll most likely know how to fix it. It can sometimes be really silly things, like aspx pages that refer to code-behind files that don't exist and annoying stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was not related to permissions after all. CSC.exe has a dependent assembly of Microsoft.VC90.CRT. I found that error in the windows event viewer. So I installed the VC++ 2008 runtime and my app runs now. I don't know, I kind of think that should have been caught by the validation step in ICE. Maybe the MS guys should look into that as this will throw a lot of people for a loop (myself included :)).