# I got "build failed" in Visual Studio 2008 and no error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird Visual Studio 2008 behaviour: build failed, no error message!!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251351/weird-visual-studio-2008-behaviour-build-failed-no-error-message)

I have build C# program for Win-CE, I make many builds and all works great.

Today I try and got: `build failed`  and I don't see any errors or any message.

I try to reset the solution and the computer and the terminal - and still same problem

What can I do? (I work with Visual Studio 2008)

thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251351/weird-visual-studio-2008-behaviour-build-failed-no-error-message

Comment: Try building it from the command line and see if there's an error listed that way? Try "clean" first? Does it build if you switch between debug and release?

Comment: The "solution" in that linked question doesn't make any sense. I suspect the same end could be accomplished by doing a "Clean Solution", and then a "Rebuild Solution". Check both the Error List *and* the Output Window for error messages. I suspect it will show you *something*.

Answer (score 0):

After you build, check the Output window, it should have the build error(s) listed.

To view the output window go to View -> Output.