# Switched targeted .NET versions and now project won't build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm running VS 2010 and I have a project which was originally set to build to .NET 4.0.  This rev of .NET is too high for many of the windows platforms this app is expected to run and so I switched it from .NET 4.0 to .NET 2.0.  Now, the project doesn't build.

At first I was getting null reference exceptions with the project resources.  I found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a061a50-a507-419b-9785-b1205bbec93b/resgen-rg0000-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) on MSDN forums which proved helpful in fixing that issue.  Essentially, the answer (among the many) that worked was to change all instances of:

```
Version=4.0.0.0
```

to

```
Version=2.0.0.0
```

... in the *.resx files.  I did this to all *.resx files I could find in the project directory.  Walla, no more null reference exceptions during the build.  However, now the project simply fails to build and the build window offers nothing in way of help to resolve.  This is literally what's there:

```
2>CoreCompile:
2>  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /reference:C:\Users\afalanga\Dev\Tools\Program\FrontEnd\Resources\WrapNativeLibrary.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Deployment.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Management.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\x86\Release\FrontEnd.exe /resource:obj\x86\Release\FrontEnd.Panel.resources /resource:obj\x86\Release\FrontEnd.PrivilegesForm.resources /resource:obj\x86\Release\FrontEnd.Main.resources /resource:obj\x86\Release\FrontEnd.Properties.Resources.resources /resource:obj\x86\Release\FrontEnd.SoftwareLicense.resources /resource:Resources\WrapNativeLibrary.dll,WindowsUpdateTool.Resources.WrapNativeLibrary.dll /resource:Resources\INativeLibrary.dll,FrontEnd.Resources.INativeLibrary.dll /target:exe /win32icon:Resources\FrontEnd.ico /win32manifest:Resources\app.manifest Environment.cs Check.cs Exceptions.cs Updater.cs LibAccess.cs PrivilegesForm.cs Form1.Designer.cs OSInfo.cs Constants.cs PersonalizationManager.cs Silent.cs drivePanel.cs drivePanel.Designer.cs Main.cs Main.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs SoftwareLicense.cs SoftwareLicense.designer.cs VerticalProgressBar.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

Is it due to the fact that the C# compiler being referenced is the 4.0 version?  At this point, I'm completely at a loss for what to check.  I'm considering a fresh checkout of the branch for this code from TFS and trying there but haven't gone that route yet.  I would appreciate any insight as everything I can see from the project properties says it should be targeting .NET 2.0 and it "should" build.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Try the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251351/weird-visual-studio-2008-behaviour-build-failed-no-error-message

Comment: After reading through the comments in the suggested thread, I'm less than impressed with Visual Studio and .NET.  It makes little sense to me that such a precarious situation exists in this product: precious in that such subtleties exist when making .NET projects.  The OP admits there's no logic to moving the code from one directory to another and then back again.  The only logic appears to be that this process makes VS correctly "link" the project to appropriate .NET targets.  Interesting, but odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're downgrading your build target, you might be better off to start with a new project, change the build target then import your code into it.  This way all your core dependencies start out right, and you'll only have to worry about the code being able to work.

Comment: That's good advice, and would probably make a great comment to the question here. It doesn't do anything to actually *answer* the question here, which is how to solve the poster's current problem.

Comment: Sometimes as with any project, backing up and starting over is the most viable solution.